# How to hide windows security authentication using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows, security

I have a problem in my code. When I call a url from server application , it requires windows security and shows pop up login. How to hide it from my application using  javascript?

Anyone knows?

Comment: What do you mean by "windows security"? I presume you are refering to BASIC web authentication.

Comment: it just like what you said :)

Comment: @Mr Zoomzoom: You can actually use Windows security in a web site, it's called [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication). If it's not the case, feel free to the edit the question and make it more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it with JavaScript. The URL you ask is protected by a security constraint defined in the server / webapp. You need to change that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you're requesting a resource which requires authorisation. You have two options:

1. Make the resource accessible to the requesting users by granting their account access
2. Allow anonymous users to access the resource

What you're asking is how to avoid the browser challenge requesting credentials - what else do you expect to happen? You can't just serve up a resource the requestor does not have access to.